# Regex Super Non-Greedy

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to build a "super non-greedy" regex, for lack of a better phrase. The problem I'm having is distilled as follows:

https://regex101.com/r/wuwOGd/2

Regex: `\/\*\*(.*?)\*\/\w+\d+`
Sample String: `/**word1*/asdf /**word2*/abc123`

What I want it to do: Only match the second token so I can extract `word2`.

What it's doing: Matching `word1*/asdf /**word2` which is technically correct, so I can't blame the regex for doing what I told it to do. But is there a way I can have the regex "fail" as soon as it has to expand beyond the first `*/`?

I'm using python in this particular case to match comment blocks attached to functions with certain signatures.

Edit:

As pointed out below, it turns out the magic word I was searching for was "tempered", not "super"!

Comment: Lol I like your new term *super non-greedy*, sounds cool

Comment: Your super non-greedy regex greedily match any character. Did you try to replace `.*?` with something like `[^*]*` or `[^\/]*`?

Comment: What about `\/\*\*([^*]*)\*\/\w+\d+`?

Comment: @anubhava why you gotta do that do me? Beat me by literally one second.

Comment: lol :) we think alike and probably `\d+` is also unnecessary

Comment: Apparently someone else thinks like us too haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/wuwOGd/6)

```
/\*{2}((?:(?!\*/).)*)\*/\w+\d+
```

Alternatively, without having to capture it (assuming PCRE). [See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/wuwOGd/7)

```
/\*{2}\K(?:(?!\*/).)*(?=\*/\w+\d+)
```

This method uses a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat) to ensure it matches any character except where `*/` is found.

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I was looking for. I've never used negative lookahead or tempered greedy token, so this answer gives me the right phrases to google and learn more. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use negated class instead of non-greedy repetition:

`\/\*\*([^*]*)\*\/\w+\d+`

https://regex101.com/r/wuwOGd/3

as the token you look for is delimited with `*` it's quite safe.

Comment: If capture value is `wo*rd2` then it may not work but may be `*` is not allowed there

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. The delimiter must be `*/` since it is a comment block. So the following string breaks it: `/**word2 * super cool*/abc123` - should extract `word2 * super cool`